# Pycharm Jupyter Interactive Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm, jupyter, interactive

Interactive matplotlib plotting is already a thing, but does not work properly in Pycharm, when used within a jupyter notebook.

The %matplotlib notebook does not work (throws no error, but I get <IPython ... JavaScript object> instead of a plot. If I plot normally (also with or without plt.show()) I just get a png and cannot interact in any way (even if, e.g., sliders are visible).

I couldn't find any answers elsewhere to this exact problem. It might be working in the browser version of jupyter, but I would like to stick to using PyCharm.

Pycharm v 2017.3 Community Edition

Comment: Do you have a problem with jupyter or with PyCharm?  What exactly *is* the problem?

Comment: problem is with pycharm. If I try to reproduce the behavior using the web version of jupyter, it works. It just does not work when running within pycharm (the notebook itself)

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
import matplotlib 
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg') 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Instead of importing only the peplos.
It's a trick I found on forum of Jetbrains
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000736584-SciView-in-PyCharm-2017-3-reduces-functionality-of-Matplotlib It works for me. With this, you skip actually the Sciview and plot in a normal matplotlib window

Comment: While I believe this should really work, I think I should have the professional version in order to uncheck the Sciview option :/

Comment: I have the same pb with the professional version. For exemple, all the interactive plot is in .png in the Sciview. So I overcome this with the code above.